# OGRToOGR when used with SQL server 2017 driver reversing the lat and longs

Tags: geojson, ogr2ogr

Have a table with shape column generated from SQL Server geo functions. When I export that as GeoJSON via Ogr2Ogr(with SQL driver 2017, on Ubuntu) its reversing the lat, longs and the resultant map shows the endpoint in Antarctic rather than US. If use the same command from windows the generated file has proper lat, and long values and the Map load fine. Do we need to do anything here with Ogr2Ogr to reverse the values before writing to GeoJSON. If so what is the option to be used with Ogr2Ogr?

Comment: Do you have same GDAL versions on both computers? Pay attention to lats and lons in your question. GeoJSON data is using lon-lat order. Do you mean that Linux version writes out lat-lon while Windows version writes lon-lat ?